# errors installing 'sads' package

Tags: r, sads

I am trying to install the sads package (on a Mac OSX) from the beta version which I have downloaded from:

http://ecologia.ib.usp.br/let/doku.php?id=engl:tutorials:rcode#species_abundance_distributions

I then run:

```
install.packages('~/Desktop/sads_0.1.03.tar.gz', repos=NULL)
```

and get the error message:

```
Error: file ‘~/Desktop/sads_0.1.03.tar.gz’ is not an OS X binary package
```

Any idea how to resolve this and install the package? It looks really useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `install.packages('~/Desktop/sads_0.1.03.tar.gz', type='source', repos=NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you downloaded is not a Mac OS binary package, which is the default for `install.packages`. Like @sgibb said, you need to specify `type = 'source'` to force R to look for a source package that you are then going to build yourself. In case the package only contains R code this is quite straightforward. If code needs to be compiled, this could be a more involved process.